# How do I know whether or not a nuclear gene is single copy?

Tags: molecular-genetics, phylogenetics, molecular-evolution, gene

As a part of a phylogenetic study, I need to find a nuclear gene that meets the following requirements:

- Single copy gene;
- Highly variable gene;
- Gene longer than 400 bps;
- Gene that gives information at the species/genus level in Gastropoda.

My candidate genes are the following: 5.8S, 18S, 28S, ACT, APN54, EF-1alpha, endo-1,4-beta-glucanase, GSTM, GSTO, GSTP, H3, ITS1, ITS2, MCP, MYO.

However, I do not know where to find whether or not they are single copy.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to use [blast](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) to search the genomes your interested in for sequences similar to your gene. If there's another copy it'll turn up in the blast results (so will orthologous genes - but they'll have lower scores than an actual copy). That relies on the annotation and genome being correct, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler: If you are lucky and your target Gastropoda is in Ensembl (http://ensemblgenomes.org/) you can just introduce the gene ID and see if it has any paralogs. A lot of other info is available for each gene.